# How to avoid error 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection' which show on second time Data saved

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a vb.net project, which connected with sql 2008 server. Where I need to saved data from datagridview. It's work well for first time. After saved one data I just clear the datagridview and input new data on that datagridview. But in this time when I start the process for saving new data from datagridview to sql it show the error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.  Parameter name: index

```
If con.State = 1 Then con.Close()

con.Open()

Using Debit_Product_ListCmd_CHK As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select *from Debit_Product_List where DEBIT_NOTE_No='" & Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(7).Value)) & "' and DEBIT_NOTE_DATE='" & Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(8).Value)) & "' and ShopGSTNO='" & _
                    Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(9).Value)) & "' and SupplierGSTNO='" & Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(10).Value)) & "' and PRODUCT_CATEGORY='" & Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(11).Value)) & "' and PRODUCT_SLNO='" & _
                    Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(0).Value)) & "' and ProductDesc=@ProductDesc", con)

   Debit_Product_ListCmd_CHK.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductDesc", Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(1).Value)))

   Dim readerRecordShowcmd As SqlDataReader = Debit_Product_ListCmd_CHK.ExecuteReader()

   If readerRecordShowcmd.Read() Then
      'Sale_Production_CUST_INVOICE_SLNO = ""
      If rsdl.State = 1 Then rsdl.Close()

      rsdl.Open("delete from Debit_Product_List where DEBIT_NOTE_No='" & Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(7).Value)) & "' and DEBIT_NOTE_DATE='" & Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(8).Value)) & "' and ShopGSTNO='" & _
                    Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(9).Value)) & "' and SupplierGSTNO='" & Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(10).Value)) & "' and PRODUCT_CATEGORY='" & Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(11).Value)) & "' and PRODUCT_SLNO='" & _
                    Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(0).Value)) & "'", conn)

      If rsdl.State = 1 Then rsdl.Close()

      rsdl.Open("delete from Debit_Product_TOTAL where DEBIT_NOTE_No='" & Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(7).Value)) & "' and DEBIT_NOTE_DATE='" & Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(8).Value)) & "' and ShopGSTNO='" & _
                        Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(9).Value)) & "' and SupplierGSTNO='" & Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(10).Value)) & "' and PRODUCT_CATEGORY='" & Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(11).Value)) & "'", conn)
   End If
End Using

con.Close()
```

I expect it will work as well as first data saved, but it show the error.

Comment: It looks like the lines of code are too long to allow efficient debugging. IMHO, all the parts of the form `Trim(UCase(ProductCart.Rows(C).Cells(7).Value))` should be separated out into variables with meaningful names. Then, use SQL parameters to put those values into the query,...

Comment: ... but do not use AddWithValue because that can introduce extra problems: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: The chances are that the value of `C` is the problem.

Comment: Is there a loop outside of this that we are not seeing that is looping through the rows in the grid? Does this account for the value of C? If so, include the loop in your question code.

Comment: What is `rsdl` ?

Comment: "to saved data from datagridview." I don't see any code that would do this. Where are you filling the grid? Does the Debit_Product_List table have a primary key? Does the Debit_Product_TOTAL table have a primary key? Are you really saving dates as strings? Is the DEBIT_NOTE_No column really a string and not a number?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. Yes I forget to use loop here. 
After use 'For' loop my problem solved.... :)